# Train Keras Model on large number of .mat files

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to train a model using neural network on Python using Keras. The data I have are a bunch of .mat files that contain data associated with ECG signals.

All .mat files have same structure but different values. However there is some differences in some array sizes in the files. For example, one file contain an array called "P_Signal" having a size of 9000, another file have it with a size of 18000.

I want to train a neural network model using Keras. As far as I know I should prepare a CSV file containing all the necessary attributes + label on each column so Keras module can understand it.

Unfortunately, this is impossible due to large arrays and fields inside the .mat files (CSV file can not load more than 16,384 columns and I have some arrays of 18000 each). So I should find another way to load those data in Keras.

Appreciate your help a lot.

Comment: You have two big misconceptions: that Keras needs CSV files, and that a CSV file has a limitation. I have CSV files with millions of rows without issue. Keras makes no assumption on how you load the data, so you can just write a generator function, and use fit_generator to pass this to Keras.

Comment: Thanks @MatiasValdenegro, is there a way in Keras to train the data directly by passing through all .mat files? Without the need to extract data from .mat into CSV and then train it.

Comment: No, you need to do this data processing, the only made solution in Keras is to load images from folders.

Comment: Thank you @MatiasValdenegro